# Set new background-size after loading new content

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is when I click on a checkbox it loads new content, it creates an overflow and I get a white space under my `background-image`.

[Here an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKb2w.png).

My JS and CSS Code is:

And this was my Javascript Code

```js
$.post(ajaxurl,data,function(response) {
    if(response!=='false') {
        $('body').html(response);
           $("body").css({ 
            "background-image": "url(bg.jpg)",  
            "background-attachment": "fixed",
            "background-size": "100%",
            "background-position": "center"
            });
    }
 });
```

```css
body.login {
    background-image: url(bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
```

I thought by new loading the image it would work (it doesn't work) but I think it is not the best idea because it would load my image 2 times and increase the traffic but I think it would be better if I could set the size new.

Any idea how I can set a new `background-size` after loading new content to avoid the white space?

Comment: Your snippet is not working

Comment: try using background-size:auto on the direction you want like horizontal vertical